# ListPicker windows phone 7 giving error

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

I have list picker in my windows phone 7 app & it works fine but whenever i try to add more options in it... it crashes i can add upto 4 or 5 options only in this list picker is there anything i can do aboout it

My working code is

xaml code

```
                <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPicker" Margin="12,3,12,12" Foreground="#FF00C000" >
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item1"/>
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Item2"/>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

& .cs code

```
            string ListPickerOperator = (this.ListPicker.SelectedItem as ListPickerItem).Content as string;

            switch (ListPickerOperator )
            {
                case "Item1":

                    break;

                case "Item2":

                    break;
            }
```

but whenever i try to make this list bigger it crashes after 4 5 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use item template. You couldn't show more than 4 or 5 items because you have to use "Full Mode template".
to use item template you should do something like this.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPicker" Margin="12,3,12,12" Foreground="#FF00C000" SelectionChanged="ListPicker_SelectionChanged" >

        <!--Normal Item template-->
        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

        <!--Full Mode template-->
        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

To populate the listpicker you only have to use itemSource propetary

```
        //list string 
        List<String> itemsList = new List<String>();

        // create 100 items 
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            itemsList.Add("item" + j);
        }

        //itemsource
        this.ListPicker.ItemsSource = itemsList;
```

to get the selectedItem you could do something like this

```
String ListPickerOperator= ((String)this.ListPicker.SelectedItem);

        switch (ListPickerOperator)
        { 

            case "item1":
                MessageBox.Show("item 1 was selected");
                break;
            case "item2":
                MessageBox.Show("item 2 was selected");
                break;
                /*
                 .
                 * .
                 * .
                 * .
                 * .
              */

        }
```